# Do I always need to "require" a package before using any function from it?

Tags: r

I have installed `rjson` in R. When I try to call a function from this package, like `toJSON`, it gives an error like "undefined function". But if I use `require("rJSON")` before to call the function it works well.

Do I always need to "require" a package before using any function from it?

Comment: You can avoid loading libraries you always require by specifying them in a custom startup. e.g. see [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html)

Comment: [You should *never* use `require`. Use `library` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you start a new R session you'll need to load the packages/libraries that contain functions you want to use, using either `library()` or `require()`.

If you load a package with the same function name as in another package, you can use `packageName::functionName()` to call the function directly. You can also use this form if you don't want to load a package (for some reason).

For example:

```
rJSON::toJSON()
```

Answer (score 1):

You not only need to install a package, but you need to load it for a particular script. That's what `require('rJSON')` is doing.

Similarly, you could use `library(rJSON)` at the beginning for similar effect.